# Wait for HTTP request to complete in controller without timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have an action in a controller similar to:

```
def action1
  uri = URI("https://exmaple.com/api")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  // request spent time about > 60s
  res = http.request(request)
  render json: res
end
```

When I call the action above. It always responds with status 504 (time out).
I want to get a response in JSON without error 504.
Can someone give me a solution for this problem? I don't want to set timeout in product environment in configuration.

Comment: What does the `capybara` tag have to do with this?

Comment: Is this intermittent issue or you get timeout always?

Answer (score 0):

As its, a 3rd party request and always takes `> 60 sec`.

so I prefer to move this code in a background job and then cache it.
and every time I send the response from the cache instead of making the API call.
also, schedule the job so that cache will be updated frequently.

To specify timeout you can try  something like that:

```
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :read_timeout => 500) {|http| http.request(request)}
```